# BASH alias to pull in a specific GIT stash when it's needed

Tags: git

In one of my dev projects, I have a specific stash that I apply for when I need to do mobile testing. I'd like to create a terminal alias to easily apply it when needed, but I'm not sure if this is possible... I know you apply a stash based on the stash number, but these numbers increment as you add more stashes.

I suppose I could create an alias that copies the specific files/changes over to my project, but I feel like using a stash would be more straightforward.

If doing this via a  stash is not possible due to the changing stash IDs, any advice on the easiest way to accomplish this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it its own name and `git stash apply` it whenever you want, as [the apply docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-apply--index-q--quietltstashgt) say,

> `apply [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]`
> Like pop, but do not remove the state from the stash list. **Unlike pop, <stash> may be any commit that looks like a commit created by stash push or stash create.**

so if the stash commit's at stash@{2} now, say `git tag mystash stash@{2}` and whenever you want to apply it you can `git stash apply mystash`.